# Growing rose plant indoor

Tags: roses, cuttings

While I grow roses indoor, should I always cut the old flowers that are going wither?

And how long does it take for a new rose flower to grow?

Answer (score 1):

Dead heading is good practice. I expect it will need a long time because of the restricted light inside.